# React-native - Conditionally set a height

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So for `<TextInput>` for ios you need to set a height. However, for android you don't need to. So I was wondering how I would set a height only when the OS matches ios. I know about platform but I get errors when I try to apply some logic. This is what I tried:

```
    <TextInput
      onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({user: input})}
      maxLength={10}
      placeholder="Enter a name"
      {(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? "height={20}" : ""}
      style={{ width: 150, textAlign: "center"}}
    />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I think the better thing to do would be:

```
const style = {
    width: 150,
    textAlign: "center",
    ...Platform.select({ios: {height: 20}})
}
<TextInput
   onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({user: input})}
   maxLength={10}
   placeholder="Enter a name"
   style={style} />
```

This way you don't duplicate the rest of the styles, and you avoid any ugly conditions in your code, so it's more readable.

You can read about Plaform.select in [react-native docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/platform-specific-code.html#platform-module)

Comment: Yeah this was more of the thing I was looking for, something that wouldn't force me to duplicate code but insert it when necessary. Thanks. Is the `...` a spread operator?

Comment: Yes. ... is a spread operator, so for iOS the height is spreaded to the style object, and for android, when you try to spread undefined, the operator is skipped.